# Conda UnsatisfiableError with linux64 and glibc

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I'm getting an error on all of my miniconda environments. I made a fresh environment just now, and still get the same error:

```
conda create --name py36 python=3.6 spyder jupyter
```

^ works fine. Then:

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/rc_iris iris
```

gives the following error:

```
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done

Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Solving environment: -

Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.

This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.

failed


UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:


Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:


  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0

  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0


Your installed version is: 2.17
```

But for some reason, if you create a whole new environment, this works:

```
conda create --name py36 -c conda-forge iris python=3.6 spyder jupyter
```

Does anyone know what's going on? How do I ensure this glibc error won't come up when I try to install something else?

Comment: The channel `conda-forge/label/rc_iris` is different from just `conda-forge`. I suppose that the package on the former channel has unsatisfiable requirements.

Comment: @darthbith the strange thing is it was happening with almost everything I was trying to install. I think the problem was with different channels, so if I'd try to install something just by "conda install" it would also throw the error. I fixed it by specifying conda-forge in every single package I was trying to install

Answer (score 6):

It's not about GLIBC, rather Conda is simply bad at reporting conflicts. Looking at the package of interest clearly shows it has a `python>=3.8` requirement. Since you locked Conda into `python=3.6`, it cannot solve, and tries to explain why.

If you really are interested in installing that release candidate, you need to do so in an environment with at least Python v3.8.